# How to run a method when variable in inherited class equals to something?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF MVVM so I don't even know if this is a proper way to do what I am trying to do.

I have this base class that I plan to use it when I want to have a UserControl (NumPad.xaml) in some of my Views.

```
class NumPad : BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _text = "";
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if(_text.Length < 6)
                _text = value;
            else if(_text.Length == 6)
                //run some function in LogInViewModel
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand NumPadCommand1 { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand NumPadCommand2 { get; set; }

    public NumPad()
    {
        NumPadCommand1 = new RelayCommand(Add1);
        NumPadCommand2 = new RelayCommand(Add2);
    }

    public void Add1(object obj)
    {
        Text += "1";
    }
    public void Add2(object obj)
    {
        Text += "2";
    }
}
```

NumPad.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding NumPadCommand1}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding NumPadCommand2}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

LogInView.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    <usercontrols:NumPad/>
</StackPanel>
```

LogInViewModel.cs

```
class LogInViewModel : NumPad
{
    public LogInViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

What I want is to check every time the Text is changed in NumPad if its length is equal to 6 notify LogInViewModel so I can run a method that searches some data, without the need of an enter button, so every time a string is added to _text through Text I want to check the length and if it equals 6I want to run a method in the class I inherit it, in this case LogInViewModel should run the method.

Comment: I think your design is flawed, `LogInViewModel` should not be `NumPad` but rather possess one.

Comment: You could add a check in the `Add1(object obj)`/`Add2(` method if the Text.Length equals 6 after you add the number. Fire an event to notify the owner object that the input is ready.

Comment: @aybe how to do what I want in a proper way?

Comment: @Alexei aybe is suggesting `NumPad` should be a property of your model; rather, that your model should not derive from `NumPad` type.  it's a remark on composition vs inheritance. it doesn't necessarily relate to your issue.

Comment: actually, forget my last comment - I deleted it. In an effort to clarify your issue... can you verify (and include in your question) whether or not you're observing `Text` to be `set` (and `OnPropertyChanged` is executed) with each keypress and\or only when `enter` is pressed  (control leaves focus perhaps) or otherwise.

Comment: Exactly that, think horizontally rather than vertically (inheritance).

Comment: @BrettCaswell `Text` is set by the 2 buttons and I can also type in it with the physical keyboard which is what I want, the TextBox Text binds to the `Text` and when `Text` is changed it updates the Text of the TextBox without the need of pressing `enter`, is this what you wanted to clarify? But to type in the TexBox with the physical keyboard I have to click to focus it which is not a problem, the buttons though don't need the TextBox to be focused.

Comment: @aybe Have an instance of `NumPad` in `LogInViewModel` ? How will the buttons find the bindings in `LogInViewModel` ? I plan to use this NumPad view in multiple views and I would not like to create RelayCommand for all the buttons in the ViewModels that I plan to use the NumPad in, that's why I inherit the commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you want to run some method in a derived class, you should define a `virtual` (or `abstract`) class in the base class:

```
class NumPad : BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _text = "";
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (_text.Length < 6)
                _text = value;
            else if (_text.Length == 6)
                SomeMethod();
            
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SomeMethod() { }

    //...
}
```

The derived classes can (or must depending on whether the method is `abstract`) then override this method:

```
class LogInViewModel : NumPad
{
    protected override void SomeMethod()
    {
        //do something....
    }
}
```

Comment: well this worked just as I wanted it to :D Thank you, but is it also the proper way to do what I want?

Comment: Yes, if I understand your issue/question correctly.